# CSS for print media : Flexbox with simple arithmetic layout imprecision

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-print

We are designing a system to generate label-sheets, which outputs HTML/CSS files which are then intended to be printed on matching label-paper.

This problem inherently involves some simple arithmetic (addition and multiplication), to place the grid of labels on the page, with corresponding margins and offsets.

### Minimal example

Let's say we have this minimal example for a 4x12 grid of labels measuring 21.2x45.7mm:

Here is the print CSS:

```
@page {
  /*size: A4;*/
  size: 210mm 297mm;
  margin-left: 9.9mm;
  margin-right: 10.1mm;
  margin-top: 20.7mm;
  margin-bottom: 21.9mm;
}


html {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 2.4mm;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.label {
  width: 45.7mm;
  height: 21.2mm;
}
```

And here is the (boring and lengthy) corresponding HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: silver;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
        <div class="label" style="background: gold;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this situation, the page is 210mm wide, and this exactly matches the length of a 4 `label` row:

```
9.9 (left margin) + 4*45.7 (label width) + 3*2.4 (column gap) + 10.1 (right margin) = 210
```

Yet, if the above content is opened in either *Firefox* or *Chrome* web browsers then printed (with default margins and 100% scaling), each line only fits 3 `label` `div`.

### Questions

- Is there some element taking space we did not account for?
- or is this an inherent limitation related to numeric precision of layout engine?
- Is there a way to fix this code, so the lay out is exact?

Comment: Maybe you've already tried playing with the `box-sizing`, but if not: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: I don't have a definite answer, but it appears to be a rounding error or a pixel getting smuggled when converting from mm to print. 
using complete values seems to work. [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-currying-f9dpu?file=/index.html) (open in newscreen and open print diaglog). 4*46+ 3*2+10+10 = 210

Comment: @Lars Thank you, it seems to indicate a rounding error in the engine. Yet, I cannot change the actual dimensions of the paper (which must also be padded with printer's calibration errors)

Comment: I assume you can control the column-gap and column's width. Only rounding their values also seems to work.  4*46 +3*2 +9.9 +10.1 = 210.

Comment: @Lars The gap matches a physical gap between the labels on the paper. Only solution here would be to reduce the printing size on each label, so the gap can be `ceil`'d to the next integer.